# how to use .addEventListener when clicking an image and counting the clicks (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

//* I am trying to click on an image and it counts the clicks*//

```
var addUp = function(counterId) {
  var count = 0;

elem.addEventListener('click', function(counterID){
    return function () {
        var counterEle = document.getElementById(counterId);
    if (counterEle)
        counterEle.innerHTML = "Picture Clicks: " + ++count;
       }
    };
   
var elem = document.getElementById('PicC');
    PicC.addEventListener("click", addUp("PicC-counter"), false);

<img id="PicC" src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px" onclick="addUp()">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function clickCount(element, listener) {
  if (!element) throw new Error("No element to listen to");
  let clickCountObj = {};
  clickCountObj.clickCount = 0;
  clickCountObj.clickDelay = 500;
  clickCountObj.element = element;
  clickCountObj.lastClickTime = 0;
  let clickCountListener = function (e) {
    if ((e.timeStamp - clickCountObj.clickDelay) < clickCountObj.lastClickTime) {
      clickCountObj.clickCount = clickCountObj.clickCount + 1;
    }
    else {
      clickCountObj.clickCount = 1;
    }
    clickCountObj.lastClickTime = e.timeStamp;
    listener.call(element, clickCountObj.clickCount, e);
  };
  clickCountObj.remove = function () {
    element.removeEventListener("click", clickCountListener);
  }
  element.addEventListener("click", clickCountListener);
  return clickCountObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made it much more complex than it needs to be.

```js
const output = document.getElementById("count");
document.getElementById('PicC').addEventListener("click",function(event){
  output.textContent = +output.textContent + 1;
});
```

```html
<img id="PicC" src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div>Click count = <span id="count">0</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what went wrong, as far as I can tell:

- `addEventListener` was inside a function
- `addEventListener` doesn't accept function parameters
- `count` was being reset every click
- and more

You can simply hook up the event listener to a function that'll increment `clicks` and add the value to the click counter.

```js
var clicks = 0;
document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click", addClick);
function addClick() {
  clicks++;
  document.getElementById("clickCounter").innerHTML = "Picture Clicks: " + clicks;
}
```

```css
#clickme {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
```

```html
<div id="clickme"></div> <!-- replaced with div for convenience -->
<div id="clickCounter">Picture Clicks: 0</div>
```

Comment: I tried to add this one because it makes the most sense to me but I am still missing something.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Image Clicker</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: black;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
  </style>

Comment: <script>
    var clicks = 0;
 document.getElementById("PicC").addEventListener("click", addClick);
 function addClick() {
   clicks++;
   document.getElementById("clickCounter").innerHTML = "Picture Clicks: " + clicks;
}

 </script>
 </head>

Comment: <body>

 <h1>Click Counter</h1>
 <p>Click image to add to counter.</p>
 
 <img id="PicC" src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div id="clickCounter">Picture Clicks: 0</div>

 </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

There's no need of *addEventListener* for such a simple task.

My suggestion (no CSS added):

```js
var i = 1;
PicC.onclick = () => {
  counter.innerHTML = i;
  i++;
}
```

```html
<img id="PicC" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Avatar">
<br>
<div>Click(s): <span id="counter">0</span></div>
```